# Executing C program object code using java in linux

Tags: java, c, linux, compilation

I was developing a simple C code generator in java in Linux and i wanted my java program to automatically compile and run the generated C code,i.e. the .out file. Though i have been able to compile it successfully I am not able to run the compiled object code. Can anyone please write the code to suggest how to execute the C code using the java program.

Comment: How about you show us what you have tried and we can help you instead of asking us to do the work for you?

Comment: The script file contains code for compiling.                    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/jerisalan/Documents/workspace/CodeGenerator/script.sh /home/jerisalan/Documents/workspace/CodeGenerator/output.c");
Process r=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/jerisalan/Documents/workspace/CodeGenerator/./output.out");

Comment: How did u solve your problem? Im facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're successfully creating the `.out` file, then you should be able to run it with one of the [`Runtime#exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) functions:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./a.out");
```

...or (more control) via the stuff in the [`Process` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). The `Process` class stuff lets you do things like control the input and output (via streams).

Comment: I have added it to my code but the execution does not start...what can it be due to???

Comment: @jerisalan: About 150 things, you'll have to show your code. It's very hard to help with coding problem without code.